# Loop with DB names inserting

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, union, dynamic-sql

I have a number of databases with tables `Table1` with the same structures. All table names are listed in the `main1` database in the table `testbases`. It is necessary in a loop to go through all the rows from the Table1 and insert them into query.

```
SELECT * FROM [DBNAME].[DBO].Table1.Client
UNION
```

To end up with a big query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [DBNAME1].[DBO].Table1.Client
UNION
SELECT * FROM [DBNAME2].[DBO].Table1.Client
UNION
SELECT * FROM [DBNAME3].[DBO].Table1.Client
UNION
SELECT * FROM [DBNAME4].[DBO].Table1.Client
UNION
etc...
```

How can I do this efficiently and automatically, so I don't need to manually change the query every time we add a client?

Comment: Normally, if you have a design with the same table in many databases and you want to use that data in single statements it a sign of a design flaw. If you want to have all this data in one dataset, why are they in different databases/tables? Seems like you shouldn't have a database by client, but a column to denote the client. Otherwise you'll going to need to go down the dynamic SQL approach to make a scalable solution and even your basic statements are only going to be difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: I know it, but it is a bad task from my university. I did not find information on the Internet on how to correctly loop through a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of the tables are identical, you could use `sp_MSforeachdb` along with an `IF EXISTS` to go through all of your databases, then insert the table if found into a temp table.  You would just need to change the column names from `col1, col2, ...` to whatever your actual table schema is.  Although you'd need to exclude any databases that contain a `Table1` table that you don't want included in your data set.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #insertTable (col1 varchar(100), col2 varchar(100),...)

DECLARE @command varchar(1000)          
SELECT @command = 'USE ?            
                   EXEC(''IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = ''''Table1'''')         
                            SELECT col1, col2, ... FROM Table1'')' 
            
INSERT INTO #insertTable (col1, col2, ...)          
EXEC sp_MSforeachdb @command
```